# Check to see if input from user is blank using Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have looked around and couldn't find a solution. My code is supposed to take input from the user and stop when there input is blank. The code was simple at first but now I think I've over complicated it so sorry about it.

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input words, enter blank to stop");
boolean working = true;
do {
    if(working == false)
    {
        break;
    }

    String a = read.next();

    if (a.equals("")) {
        working = false;
        System.out.println("no data");    
    } else {
        Container.addWord(a);
    }
} while (working == true);
```

Thanks.

Comment: The first "if" statement is not useful, because it working pass to false you won't enter in the while loop next time ;)

Comment: have you tried `scanner.hasNext()` method?

Comment: @azro he sets it to true at the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change next() to nextLine():

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input words, enter blank to stop");
boolean working = true;
do {
    if (working == false) {
        break;
    }
    String a = read.nextLine();
    if (a.isEmpty()) {
        working = false;
        System.out.println("no data");
    } else {
        Container.addWord(a);
    }
} while (working == true);
```

Comment: you missed something. what is `.isEmpty()`?

Comment: @AhmadMoawad was just waiting for the time limit until I could accept an answer to go down.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `String#trim().isEmpty()`

It'll also consider strings like `"     "` to be empty.

```
do {
    String a = read.next();

    if (a.trim().isEmpty()) {
        working = false;
        System.out.println("no data");    
    } else {
        Container.addWord(a);
    }
} while (working);
```

Comment: this wasn't the issue but it is useful knowledge so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code could be replaced with the following:

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input words, enter blank to stop");
while(true) {    
    if (!read.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("no data");
        break; 
    }
    String a = read.next();
    Container.addWord(a);
}
```

I also removed the `working` variable and replaced it with a `break` statement.

If you change `read.next()` to `read.nextLine()` be sure to also update the `read.hasNext()` to `read.hasNextLine()`.

Comment: Thanks, my code looked similar to this at first but then I ruined it trying to fix my issue.

Comment: @Aueisbiejei3i939 just realized there's no need to define `working`, so I removed it from the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit more elegant version

```
public static void main(String...args){
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = null;
    System.out.println("Enter text:");
    while(!(line=read.nextLine()).equals("")){
        System.out.println("Your text:"+line);
        System.out.println("Enter text or press enter to exit:");
    }

    System.out.println("Bye bye !!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourString.isEmpty() || yourString.equals("")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the whole thing:

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input words, enter blank to stop");
boolean working = true;
do {
    String keyEntered = read.nextLine();

    if (keyEntered.isEmpty()) {
        working = false;
        System.out.println("No data");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You entered: " + keyEntered);
    }
} while (working);
```